# PHP Grab User's Form Selection

Tags: php, sql, forms, select

Currently, I am grabbing a list from a database via an SQL statement and then injecting it into a drop down menu via php. However, now I need to tell which one the user selects from the list. Any easy way to do this without actually listing out all the option statements?

```
echo "<select name='countydomain' mehod='post' onchange='form.submit()'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value=selection'" . $row['countydomain'] . "'>" . $row['countydomain']  ."
    </option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: For the `value=selection`, have you considered using `$row['id']`? Assuming you have an `ID` column.

Comment: That is basically what countydomain will be serving as. I am more wondering how to figure out which selection the user makes.

Comment: Please add the full `<form />` code you're using. A `select` alone won't post itself.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can modify your select's onchange to point to a custom javascript function. Have the function get the value of the select (probably want to pass *this* as a parameter to the function) and do whatever you need to, finally call `document.forms["myformID"].submit();`

Let's create an example javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkFirst(theSelect){
    alert(theSelect.value);
    document.forms["myform"].submit();
  }
</script>
```

And your markup would look like:

```
echo "<select name='countydomain' mehod='post' onchange='checkFirst(this);'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do this on the server-side. If so, use `$_POST['countydomain']`.

Comment: The $_POST['countydomain'] isn't showing what they select. Just refreshing the page...?

Comment: I've added a comment to the question - please add the full `form` code to it.